# Best approach for types - Typescript frontend TCL backend

Tags: typescript, tcl, typescript-typings

Soon I'm starting to rewrite frontend for pretty old application which backend (api) is written in TCL language.
I have small doubt with types I will use in Typescript.

Previously I worked on NodeJS (backend) and Typescirpt (frontend) app and I was having similar doubts, I simply didn't want to manualy type same interfaces/types on both sides.
After researching here on stackoverflow, I came up with simple but great solution of having */shared* folder which was a container for all types and interfaces. Thanks to that I could share exactly same types between frontend and backend.

Back to question.
As I said, now I'm working with Typescript connected to TCL Api.
And here is the question:
**What is the best aproach to prevent from manually typing all the interfaces in Typesript ?**
I thought about writing simple TCL type/interface generator (based on database to which TCL is connected), but this would mean I would need to always remember about "executing" generation of types...
But well, nothing better I could think of, maybe someone from stackoverflow will have better idea.

As an examaple:

On backend side (api) I have 'users' table (mysql), which consist of name, email, gender, role_id (it has more, but it guess it doesnt matter)
Of course I can manually create User Interface in Typescript, but I'm looking for a way to well, not do that manually :)
And my first thought was to write file generator, that would create typescript interfaces based on e.g. mysql ‚users’ table

Comment: Are you planning on versioning your backend api?

Comment: I guess generating stuff is the right approach, but your question feels a bit too general to answer right now. Could you add an _example_ of what you'd like to generate and where you want to start from?

Comment: @DonalFellows I described example of what I want to do

Comment: Thanks. This all sounds a bit ORM-y, so I'm going to have to guess a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, you're normally recommended to use [TDBC](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TdbcmysqlCmd/tdbc_mysql.htm) for accessing MySQL from Tcl.

```tcl
package require tdbc::mysql

# Read the manual page for options; I really don't know what's sensible for you
set db [tdbc::mysql::connection new ...]
```

Given the above connection, you can then use table metadata to build interfaces. This writes the definition to standard output; I'm not sure what the best way of getting that across to Typescript is.

```tcl
# Build an interface description from the table metadata
set TableName "Users"
puts "interface $TableName {"
dict for {columnName columnInfo} [$db columns $TableName] {
    set type [dict get $columnInfo type]
    # SQL has all sorts of types that you don't care about, so you will need to tweak this
    # for what's actually there. Experiment!
    switch $type {
        bigint - integer - smallint - tinyint - double - float - numeric {
            # Column is some kind of numeric type
            puts "    $columnName : number;"
        }
        char - varchar - longvarchar - text {
            # Column is text
            puts "    $columnName : string;"
        }
        ... ...
    }
}
puts "}"
```

Now that you have that, you can also build some objects:

```tcl
$db foreach -columnsvariable c rowData "SELECT * FROM $TableName" {
     # Give each value a simple unique name; you can do better!
     puts "let obj_[incr index] : $TableName = {"
     dict for {columnName columnData} $rowData {
         set type [dict get $c $columnName type]
         if {$type in {char varchar longvarchar text}} {
             set quoted [string map {"\\" "\\\\" "\"" "\\\""} $columnData]
             puts "    $columnName : \"$quoted\","
         } else {
             puts "    $columnName : $columnData"
         }
     }
     puts "};"
}
```

For simple types, this is going to be good enough.

Comment: WARNING! This is _not tested code_ as I have neither MySQL nor any experience with Typescript; I've had to guess a lot from documentation and other SO questions…

Comment: Also, this is by no means an ORM! It's just basic code to try to map the table over and schlep over a snapshot of the data.

Comment: This is great answer!
Thank you very much !